# How to deploy sparkjava web program to linux server?

Tags: java, jetty, spark-java

I have write a java web project using SparkJava framework. And I have a Linux Server, I want to deploy it to the server. SparkJava using jetty server, should I first download the jetty server in the Linux Server?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to download the Jetty server. SparkJava framework has the Jetty server embedded, so if you run your application as a jar, the Jetty server jars should already be there.

You have 2 options:

- Run your application as a jar
- Run your application as a war in a Serlet container of your choise. In this case you have to download the server container you want, for example Tomcat.

Comment: How would I run the application as a JAR?

Comment: Nevermind. The Java documentation clearly explains this. For those interested: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven you can package all dependencies with the assembly plugin. Add the following to your pom.xml file in the plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>name-of-application</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                 <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run maven compile and you will have a self contained jar that you can run on the command line:

```
java -jar name-of-application-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

If you are using the default settings your app should be running at http://localhost:4567